# Replace Null value of django objects with default value

Tags: python, django

I would like to replace null value in my django objects with the default value :

Example :

```
class Buy(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False,default=timezone.now)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True,default=timezone.now)
    name = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,  max_length=200,default='')
```

Here is my script :

```
for buy in Buy.objects.all():
    for f in Buy._meta.get_fields():
        field = eval("buy." + f.name+" is None")
        if field:
            field = Buy._meta.get_field(f.name).get_default()
        buy.save()
```

but when i make a json export with dumpdata i still have

> "name" : null,

in my json for a lot of objects instead of

> "name": ""

.

I don't understand my script for migrating the null value of my object to "" seems to be correct.

Regards

Comment: `if field` only runs if the field is not null, did you mean `if not field`?

Comment: @mousetail i've made a doncidtion before :  field = eval("buy." + f.name+" is None")

Comment: Oh I see. But that won't work. `field` is a local variable. Changing it will have no effect. Why not use `getattr` and `setattr` rather than `eval`?

Comment: @mousetail i will dig your suggestion

Comment: @mousetail i think you're right i'am testing it right now if you want make an answer with your comment and i will validate it thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, don't use `eval`, since it is unsafe. 99% of the time there is a better way.

Secondly, changing a local variable will have no effect. The replaced value will be destroyed when the function returns and the stack frame is popped.

So, I suggest using `getattr()` and `setattr()` to perform your query:

```
setattr(buy, f.name, getattr(buy, f.name) or Buy._meta.get_field(f.name).get_default())
buy.save()
```

This oneliner will replace any falsy values with the default value, through the magic of `or`. Then we can use `setattr` to assign the correct value to the correct attribute. No `eval` needed.